# How to combine bands from different rasters using the global mapper raster calculator?

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, global-mapper

I am wondering how to specify what raster you are getting the band from in the global mapper raster calculator? When you open it with a more then one raster open you can check the boxes to define which ones you use. But once you are in the actual calculator there is no way (that i can see) to specify which raster band 1 is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you specify the number of the bands to use, the formula to apply to them and how many and hit ok it will prompt you to select which raster (from the ones checked off when you start raster calculator) the bands correspond to.